# How to get historical price from Chainlink price

Tags: oracles, chainlink, price

I want to check the price at a previous timestamp, and I see I can use the
getHistoricalPrice function
.

```
     * Returns historical price for a round id.
     * roundId is NOT incremental. Not all roundIds are valid.
     * You must know a valid roundId before consuming historical data.
     *
     * ROUNDID VALUES:
     *    InValid:      18446744073709562300
     *    Valid:        18446744073709562301
     *    
     * @dev A timestamp with zero value means the round is not complete and should not be used.
     */
    function getHistoricalPrice(uint80 roundId) public view returns (int256) {
        (
            uint80 id, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.getRoundData(roundId);
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }
```

How do I determine the `roundId` of the timestamp I want to query?
(sources https://docs.chain.link/docs/historical-price-data/)

Answer (score 1):

Deploying an onchain iterator would be the fastest solution here, but is this for a smart contract or py/js script? Truth be told, there's no real way to do what you're looking for in a timely or cheap manner. Whatever the case, you would need to iterate the rounds backwards until you get your timestamp or close enough.

Comment: This is for a smart contract. Will try to use the manual implementation, that iterates backwards at least for now before I find something else, hopefully.

Comment: Don't just blindly try to check the chainlink contract itself. Check the phaseAggregators(phaseId) public mapping to get a collection of addresses (where the data is stored). the highest you can go is phaseId(). These aggregators also have their own roundId mappings... so depending on how many phases there are, you are in for a DYNAMIC amount of memory consumption...

This bytecode will be large and expensive. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, came across a useful project whose implementation I have borrowed. I was having a hard time wrapping my head around phases.
 I understand the implementation up to function roundIdsToSearch; then things start getting complicated.

Am trying to think about how to adapt function roundIdsToSearch, since the data am collecting is not likely to extend beyond a single day. How to treat daysToFetch and dataPointsToFetchPerDay parameters.

Comment: I am doing something a bit different. I need to get historical prices: microwindow(5m) and macroWindow(1h), from current block.timestamp. Here is my project, and my implementation is under function _fetch https://github.com/VictorONN/OverlayChainlinkfeed/blob/master/Chainlink/OVLV1ChainlinkFeed.sol 

If you get some time to have a look at this I would appreciate thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, chainlink doesn't update that often. If I had known that's what you were after then I would have just advised against it. HOWEVER, this may be useful to deploy if you had some kind of offchain bot that needed this to reduce the frequency of your API calls.

Comment: Most ETH mainnet oracles update once a day...

Comment: There are a lot of DeFi projects that use Chainlink oracles. Don't they use them for on-demand tasks like closing positions or liquidating positions? I am trying to implement Chainlink for similar functionality since TWAPs can be more easily manipulated

Comment: You are correct! However, the only thing I have to disagree with on your approach is the fact that you are trying to collect data that doesn't exist. Since most oracles update once a day. Your candle resolution is limited to the 1w period. Those on-demand tasks are not eagerly evaluated and use LINK to evaluate + execute on those specified conditions OR they run a centralized bot to do those rebalances.

Comment: Could you share a repo with an implementation of this other approach I could use to achieve what I intend?

Comment: I haven't actually peeked at it, but I'm pretty sure Yearn has what you are after.